# declare variable in swift

Tags: swift, variables, declare

I have this code and my question is, How declare variable "connection" to global variable? I need share connection in my project for other func

var connection = ???

```
do {
var configuration = PostgresClientKit.ConnectionConfiguration()
configuration.host = "127.0.0.1"
configuration.database = "example"
configuration.user = "bob"
configuration.credential = .scramSHA256(password: "welcome1")

let connection = try PostgresClientKit.Connection(configuration: configuration)
let text = "SELECT start();"
try connection.prepareStatement(text: text).execute()
} catch {
print(error)
}
```

I tried use struct, but still I have problem with declare conn - Value of type '[conn]' has no member 'prepareStatement' Any idea?

```
import UIKit
import PostgresClientKit

struct conn {
    let conn : Connection
}
var myconnection = [conn]()

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            var configuration = PostgresClientKit.ConnectionConfiguration()
            configuration.host = "127.0.0.1"
            configuration.database = "example"
            configuration.user = "bob"
            configuration.credential = .scramSHA256(password: "welcome1")

            let aaa = try PostgresClientKit.Connection(configuration: configuration)
            let bbb = conn ( conn: aaa)
            myconnection.append(bbb)
            
            let text = "SELECT start();"
            try myconnection.prepareStatement(text: text).execute()
            
            
        } catch {
            print(error) // better error handling goes here
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: As a property if your struct/object?

Comment: example or link please

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

Comment: please check my update @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but I think I see your problem. Your code is failing on this line:

```swift
try myconnection.prepareStatement(text: text).execute()
```

but `myconnection`, as you've declared it above, is of type `[conn]`:

```swift
var myconnection = [conn]()
```

If you want to call `prepareStatement(text:)` on the first element of your array, you can do this:

```swift
try myconnection[0].conn.prepareStatement(text: text).execute()
```

You need the `.conn` in the middle because the array is an array of `conn` structs, which have `conn` properties that are actually of type `Connection`.

---

It's worth noting that, at least in this function, you could just call `prepareStatement(text:)` on `aaa` before you create `bbb` out of it and store it in the array.